# Deleting listbox's items using context menu c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, contextmenu

So I have a listbox in my program and I want the user to be able to delete a specific item in it by accessing its context menu and clicking delete. Everything seems to be working fine if I delete its items in order (from top item to the last item). However, I get a debugging error when I don't delete the items in order. I want to know how will I be able to delete an item of my choice.

This is the code that will execute once the user right clicks an item in the listbox:

```
public void listBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        index = listBox.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
        {
            if (index == listBox.SelectedIndex)
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the click event handler:

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox.Items.Remove(listBox.SelectedItems[index]);
}
```

This is the error message from the IDE:
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

Comment: what's the error message

Comment: Do you need a ObservableCollection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listBox.SelectedIndex` returns collection of selected items. Since user selects only one item, this collection has only one item with index 0. Trying to delete item with non-zero index will cause an error. Use `listBox.Items.RemoveAt(index)` instead:

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
}
```